# format & validate multiple email addresses from textarea

Tags: javascript

I need to trim out white space and separate with semicolons.  When thats done validate email addresses are in a proper email format before I pass into the database.  Something like this:

"tom@yahoo.com;bob@yahoo.com"

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's on I did in JavaScript using jQuery Validate:

```
$.validator.addMethod('emailList', function(value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) return true;

    var flag = true;
    var addresses = value.replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        flag = /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i.test(addresses[i]);
    }
    return flag;
}, '');
```

You can change the split to `;` if that's your delimiter.

Comment: hey that worked...but If I put "+email@email.com"...it will pass

Answer (score 0):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

That has a lot of information on regular expressions and email. I would use a simple split.

http://www.somacon.com/p355.php

Removing White space